# Prove that $m\ddot{r}=\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{l}{mr^2} \frac{dr}{d\theta})$ (Goldstein)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

$$mr^2\dot{\theta}=l$$
$$m\ddot{r}-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}=f(r) \tag{1}$$

where $\dot{x}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$..

I have to show that

$$(1)=\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{l}{mr^2} \frac{dr}{d\theta})-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}=f(r)$$

I was trying to move from backward

$$\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{l}{mr^2} \frac{dr}{d\theta})=m\dot{\theta}^2\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}$$

I can't move on. Here, I was differentiating $\dot{\theta}\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ respect to $\theta$ for the reason $\dot{\theta}$ is constant. Hence I had removed it from differentiation (I don't think I should remember that $\dot{\theta}$ function has "$\theta$").

using chain rule as someone said in the comment.. I got something just like this

$$\dot{r}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{\theta \cdot  l}{mr^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}$$

I can rewrite it as $$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{\theta l}{mr^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta})$$

I got a closed answer to that one. But not exactly.. Even, I was thinking why $\dot{r}$ should work for that reason cause in my main equation I had second-order differential of $r$

Comment: Use the chain rule in $dr/dt=(dr/d\theta)(d\theta/dt)$ and substitute the first equation into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dot{r}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\dot{\theta}=\frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}$$

$$m\ddot{r}=m\dot{\theta}\frac{d\dot{r}}{d\theta}=
\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)$$